# Почему передавая json через pjax post создается множество переменных?

Tags: json, pjax

Я получаю с одного сервиса данные в виде *json* объекта. Делаю это в *javascript*'е. Потом эти данные хочу передать на сервер через *pjax* методом `post`

Когда я это делаю, то *pjax* на каждый ключ в объекте создает свою переменную.
В результате, если я передаю предположим

```js
    var info = {
    "id": 11179222,
    "first_name": "Виктор",
    "last_name": "Скородум",
    "sex": 2,
    "nickname": "",
    "screen_name": "Victor_Scorodoom",
    "bdate": "6.6.1987"
  }
```

с вот таким запросом:

```js
$.pjax.reload({
  container: '#content',
  type: 'POST',
  url: path,
  data: info,
  push: true,
  replace: false,
  timeout: 1000
});
```

то в пост запросе улетает

```html
info[id]:11179222
info[first_name]:Виктор
info[last_name]:Скородум
info[sex]:2
info[nickname]:
info[screen_name]:Victor_Scorodoom
info[bdate]:6.6.1987
```

Это так и должно быть и я чего-то не знаю? Или я что-то не так делаю? И если я не так делаю, то как можно передать json, чтоб не создавалось множество переменных?

Можно конечно обернуть в `stringify`, а на сервере делать разбор. Но так не хотелось бы. Или может так и надо?

Comment: Именно так. Рекомендую все, что после "UPD" написать как ответ на ваш же вопрос, может кому-нибудь еще понадобится

Comment: Да, в начале так и сделал. Потом подумал, что правильнее сделать UPD)) Всё подправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поизучав вопрос было найдено, что ajax/pjax так и работают. И это верно. И так и должно быть. С этим ничего не сделать. Если малый объем данных нужно передать, не стоит беспокоиться.
Если же речь будет идти о тысячах переменных (что существенно увеличит загрузку данных), то скорее лучше будет передавать данные как строку

```
$.pjax.reload({
  container: '#content',
  type: 'POST',
  url: path,
  data: {
    jsonData: JSON.stringify(data)
  },
  push: true,
  replace: false,
  timeout: 1000
});
```

а на сервере делать json_decode($_POST['jsonData']);