# При передаче большого JSON теряется часть данных

Tags: php, javascript

Есть JSON, около 45 килобайт. Это список состоящий из объектов:

```
{
   name: 'My Name',
   add: true,
   type: 'group'
}
```

Этот список передается ajax'ом на сервер. Тут то и начинается магия - у последнего объекта в списке нет поля `type`.  Прямо перед отправкой это поле есть.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В лимитах веб-сервера на post. У вас nginx, apache? И, запрос обрезается или только одного поля не хватает, а закрывающие } на месте?

Comment: Apache. Но до лимита еще очень далеко, я успешно принимаю пакеты куда большего объема.

Comment: @Илья Бизунов может быть дело в методе передачи? Вы гет используете? Попробуйте заменить на пост.

Comment: Передаю POST'ом, конечно.

Comment: циклом генерируете?

Comment: Да, циклом. $.each из JQuery.

Comment: ну, показывайте ваш цикл

Answer (score 0):

Я когда-то тут задавал вопрос **[Почему передавая json через pjax post создается множество переменных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/453920/191482)**

Собственно, он тоже имеет отношение к вашему вопросу. Если у вас куча переменных, то логично, что играет ограничение на их количество со стороны сервера. И тогда можно увеличить `max_input_vars` в настройках `php.ini`. Но лучше сделать их в виде одной переменной, предварительно сделав JSON объект и далее с помощью  **[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** отправлять.

Примерно так:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: path,
  data: {
    jsonData: JSON.stringify(data) // <--- ключевой момент
  }
  success: function(response){
    // ...
  }
});
```

На сервере будет примерно так:

```
json_decode($_POST['jsonData']);
```